# Replacing orange peel with orange powder

Tags: ingredients, adjuncts

I am having a hard time finding bitter orange peel in my region, but I did find bitter orange powder.

Can I achieve the same results with the powder instead of the peel? Should I use the same quantity or increase or decrease?

I will it to brew my first wit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal orange peel as well.  Just buy an orange or two, peel them avoiding the pith and use that.  I have never found it a big difference between bitter orange and "sweet" orange peel.  Most of the stuff in the homebrew stores is pretty old, at least around me anyway.

The orange powder may work, but without knowing whats in it or what it is I can't guess.

Comment: Thanks. I have also found other sources recomending to use fresh zest instead of the dehidrated peel, but I am still unsure of the quantity. Should I still use the same quantity, or does it require more, since the normally, fresh is not as strong as dried. This is the recipe I will brew, btw: http://byo.com/stories/issue/item/1747-hoegaardenwit

Comment: In my opinion, if you like orange peel essence in your beer then zest a full orange and put it in right at the end of the boil.  If you are a little unsure use a half an orange. I'll standardize said orange to be slightly bigger than a baseball.  If in the final beer the orange isn't good enough for you, serve it with a wedge of orange.  That's what I do.